# Laravel 5.4 and oAuth2 - get authenticated client in controller

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm pretty new at Laravel and this is my first API. I used Laravel Passport for authentication. Is there any elegant way to get authenticated client in the controller? I need to load different data depending on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auth::user()` to get authenticated user as same as if you use standard authentication